# How to add custom Hibernate types in Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Problem: I'm gonna use [Hibernate-Types](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) by @vlad-mihalcea. But I need to use my own ObjectMapper instance (Spring bean). How to do it?

Details: Vald explains [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-types-customize-jackson-objectmapper/) how to register custom ObjectMapper. However I still don't know where exactly add the properties.

Is the `properties` object supposed to be passed to `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` like the following?

```java
@Bean
@Primary
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
        DataSource dataSource,
        JpaProperties jpaProperties,
        JpaSchemaGenerationProperties schemaGenerationProperties) {

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = builder
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .packages("foo", "bar")
            .persistenceUnit("default")
            .properties(jpaProperties.getHibernateProperties(dataSource))
            .build();

    Map<String, Object> jpaPropertyMap = createDefaultJPAConfigMap(env, schemaGenerationProperties);
    // Should I add the property here?

    factory.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaPropertyMap);
    return factory;
}
```